# Retrieving parent-child ordered data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, hierarchy

I have a table with say following fields

```
id, name, sub_id
1, test1, ""
2, test2, ""
3, test3, ""
4, test4, ""
5, test5, 1
6, test6, 1
7, test7, 2
8, test8, 3
```

I want to retrieve the data from this table ordered in such a way that it is ordered by id and then sub_id if it exists.
for example:

```
id, name, sub_id
1, test1, ""
5, test5, 1
6, test6, 1
2, test2, ""
7, test7, 2
3, test3, ""
8, test8, 3
4, test4, ""
```

I tried group by and order by but that didnt work.

Comment: Please try using an alias for the group by field.

Comment: I don't think you can retrieve a whole tree structure (which is what you have) in a single query using your structure:

You might benefit from this resource: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to understand, that the sub_id references the same table again.
After that i realized you need to join the table on itself.

Try this query

```
SELECT
  a.*
FROM
  `some_table` AS a
  LEFT JOIN `some_table` AS b
    ON
      b.id = a.sub_id
ORDER BY
  IF (b.id IS NULL, 0, a.sub_id) ASC,
  a.id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't show ordering by id then sub_id, but if you wanted to it would be easier to do:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table ORDER BY id,ifnull(sub_id,0);
```

I'm assuming that "" is a null value, otherwise you would need a different function than ifnull.